# com.sun.faces.logicalViewMap for Lookup / Popup JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a requirement where once a lookup is used i do not want the lookup view to exist in the com.sun.faces.logicalViewMap.

can someone provide me some hits as to how this can be achieved.

basically i do not want the  logicalViewMap to have more that 4 view and i set the value in web.xml.

but since my screens have lookup pages (opened thru window.open and page is JSF) i end up with the case that the lookup add up to the view and after clicking on 5 view.. the main page throws a ViewExpiredException .

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
 <param-value>4</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
  <param-value>4</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that by fixing numberOfViewsInSession at 15 we were able to solve the issue.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
  <param-value>15</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
  <param-value>4</param-value>
</context-param>
```